Launching dialog takes atleast 2 to 3 seconds to open. This time varies too. How can we improve this
Launching a dialog in Google Apps Script project takes around 2 to 3 seconds to open. When the project is big, it takes even 6 seconds some times. How can this be optimized.
let html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('HelloWorld');
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html.evaluate(), 'Hello World');

Create a basic Hello World html and try to launch using  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog. We will observe the there is a delay in between the Menu click and dialog opening.
Sample Code
function onOpen() { 
        var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
        ui.createMenu('Custom Menu') 
        .addItem('Open Hello World Dialog', 'openHelloWorldDialog') 
        .addToUi(); 
} 

function openHelloWorldDialog() { 
    var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('helloWorld') 
    .setWidth(300) 
    .setHeight(200); 
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Hello World Dialog'); 
}


There could be a lot of reasons why you're experiencing it, but it is quite hard to point out with just the piece of code given. Kindly edit your post to add more details and context.

Highly doubt there can be anything done to optimize this.

There is nothing much in the project.
function onOpen() {
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();  // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
.addItem('Open Hello World Dialog', 'openHelloWorldDialog')
.addToUi();
}
function openHelloWorldDialog() {
var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('helloWorld')
.setWidth(300)
.setHeight(200);
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Hello World Dialog');
}

Just a basic html opening takes around 2 seconds for us. And in our main project it takes around 2 seconds just to enter into our project where we have our Menu handlers written. We are kind of stuck here without any clues. Is there any way we can identify if it is a Global Variable issue or Project Size issue or something else

Please [edit] the question to add that [mre] there rather than giving it in a comment.

What is the content of the .html file? How is the dialog opened? How large is your Apps Script project?

The .html doesnt contain much. just a h1 tag that prints Hello World

Is there any way we can identify if it is a Global Variable issue or Project Size issue or something else How big is your project?

There will be a initial delay for the apps script to load the html. However, you can adapt Best practices according to Google. From your code, you should

avoid templated html and use asynchronous google.script.run instead

Other recommendationsinclude things like loading JavaScript last and using faster libraries.
